# Problem with Running gem5: gem5.opt isn't generated after running /usr/bin/env python3.9 $(which scons) build/RISCV/gem5.opt -no-pie

Tags: python-3.x, g++, scons, riscv, gem5

I am trying to set up gem5 for RISCV on Ubuntu 18.04. I first ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
apt install m4 zlib1g-dev scons python-six python-dev
git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
```

Then I tried running the following command:

```
/usr/bin/env python3.9 $(which scons) build/RISCV/gem5.opt
```

Everything starts perfectly but then it gives an error that there is no working python environment. So, I had to edit the file SConstruct under gem5 directory on line 521 from:

```
py_version = conf.CheckPythonLib()
```

to:

```
vi = sys.version_info
py_version = (vi.major, vi.minor, vi.micro)
```

After I did this, it started to work but it then complained about PIE objects:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.a(myreadline.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

So, I finally ran it with the following command and it finished without any errors:

```
/usr/bin/env python3.9 $(which scons) build/RISCV/gem5.opt -no-pie
```

However, I can not find gem5.opt under build/RISCV and therefore can not run gem5. I would really appreciate it if anyone has any suggestion that might fix the issue. Thank you!

Comment: `CheckPythonLib()` is a gem5 custom checker. Likely you should report this issue on their bug tracker. https://www.gem5.org/documentation/reporting_problems/